# Select unique rows based on condition stored in another table

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, drizzle

I want to select rows based on conditions that is fetched from the database. The tables structure are mentioned below.

```
# Questions Table: 
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════╗
║ id         ║ chapter_id    ║ weight ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╣
║ question-1 ║ first         ║ 1      ║
║ question-2 ║ second        ║ 1      ║
║ question-3 ║ third         ║ 1      ║
║ question-4 ║ first         ║ 2      ║
║ question-5 ║ third         ║ 2      ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════╝
```

```
# Patterns Tables
╔════╦═════════════════╦════════╗
║ id ║ question_number ║ weight ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬════════╣
║ p1 ║ 1               ║ 1      ║
║ p2 ║ 2               ║ 1      ║
║ p3 ║ 3               ║ 1      ║
║ p4 ║ 4               ║ 2      ║
║ p5 ║ 5               ║ 2      ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩════════╝
```

```
# Patterns to SubChapters 
╔════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ pattern_id ║ chapter_id    ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ p1         ║ first         ║
║ p2         ║ second        ║
║ p3         ║ third         ║
║ p4         ║ first         ║
║ p4         ║ second        ║
║ p5         ║ second        ║
║ p5         ║ third         ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Now I want to select a unique question for each matching pattern

Required Output:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ pattern_id ║ question_number ║ question_id ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ p1         ║ 1               ║ question-1  ║
║ p2         ║ 2               ║ question-2  ║
║ p3         ║ 3               ║ question-3  ║
║ p4         ║ 4               ║ question-4  ║
║ p5         ║ 6               ║ question-5  ║
╚════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════╝

// p1 can be from first chapter with weight = 1 (i.e. question-1)
// p2 can only be second chapter with weight = 1 (i.e. question-2)
// p3 can be from third chapter with weight = 1 (i.e. question-3)
// p4 can be from first with weight = 2 (question-4)
// p5 can be from third with weight = 2 (question-5)

// similarly if there are multiple options, it should choose randomly from one of them.

// Weight are also considered a condition and the generated question_id column should be unique
```

I am quite new to sql databases still learning, please let me know what can done to tackle this kind of issue? I am using postgres with drizzle orm for my quiz application.

Currently, I have tackled this situation with 100 separate sequential queries, which takes much longer and isn't suitable for running in a cloud function.
[Current Solution](https://github.com/sahrohit/pracharya/blob/cdacae336b8327fc8d7263e9beba55ab44fc9d4b/src/server/api/routers/test.ts#L154C1-L256C6)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with the exact query, but I suggest you split up the task into 2 parts:

1. Make a query joining all tables with duplicate questions.
2. Select unique questions among the results.

For the first part you can use `JOIN` expression. For example, you can join Patterns to Questions using question number/id. As I understand, you also want to join Questions with "Patterns to SubChapters" table using chapter id. You can combine both results into one table with `UNION` operator.

Once you did that, you should have a table with duplicate questions. You can pick unique questions according to your criteria with `SELECT DISTINCT ON`. You will specify what unique column do you want (question_id) and how to choose one row among duplicates (`ORDER BY ...`)

Hope that helps!